# Adding AdBannerView to application creates memory leak

Tags: iphone, ios4, iad

I have a working iPhone app using SDK 4.0. It shows no leaks in the 'Instruments' tool, and I am fairly convinced that the code does not have any memory leaks.

I then tried to add iAds to the app, and it started showing memory leaks. In order to nail down the problem, I removed all additional code.

All that is left is an added AdBannerView to the .xib file (without doing a single modification to the working version of the code without iAds). This shows memory leaks.

Every time the view loads, the 'Instruments' tool shows 5 leaked blocks of 16 bytes each, with the Responsible Library 'Foundation', and Responsible frame

```
[NSCFString copywithZone:]
```

Further running the app gives me leaks from the Responsible library 'iAd' (2 leaks of 48 bytes each), and the responsible frame:

```
[AdBrandingFrame initWithFrame:]
```

Further, I also get 48 byte leaks with the responsible library 'UIKit' and responsible frame

```
-[UIView _createLayerWithFrame:]
```

Since there is absolutely no addition to my working non-leaking code, except an added AdBannerView to the .xib file, I wonder if it is Apple's code that causes the leak. Although the leak is relatively small, I would like to iron it out. I understand that there is a possibility that a leak shows up even though there may not be one (the pointers might still be held by the OS in some way that Leaks does not know about - It would be great to know if this is the case).

So I had two questions:
1) Is there any chance the problem is actually my code, and the leak for some reason only shows up after adding AdBannerView? If there is such a possibility, I would run another thorough code test.

2) If this is a problem with Apple's code and any of you have encountered this, are there any workarounds you have found?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [iAds are leaking memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571579/iads-are-leaking-memory)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. I think this has been fixed in IOS 4.1
When I test in 4.0 I got a couple leaks "NSCFString copyWithZone"
When testing in 4.1 all is good.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check to see if this resolves the problem for me.